# SAS convert ascii back to integer value

Tags: integer, sas, ascii

Hi I am trying to convert an ascii character back to the corresponding integer value in SAS.

I can get from an integer to the ascii, but how can I get back to the values?  I know have a character 'R' how can I extract the value of 82?

I can use the byte function to get ascii values but how can I get from an ascii to an integer?

```
data _null_;
      do i=0 to 255;
            x=byte(i);
            put i= x=;
      end;
      y=rank('a');
      put y=;
run;
```

THank you!

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67239/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm

Comment: What does the input function have to do with anything?

Comment: I'm not sure why you ask the question when the answer is in the question, anyway.  RANK.

Answer (score 2):

The `rank` function is exactly the function you should use.

```
data _null_;
      do i=0 to 255;
            x=byte(i);
            y=rank(x);
            put i= x= y= x= $HEX.;
      end;

run;
```

It gives it back in the ASCII collating sequence only, so this is not Unicode-compliant nor is it DBCS compliant.

You can also use the `$HEX.` format to display how a character is stored (physically), which should generally be the hexadecimal representation of the integer `rank` returns for ascii characters.  This would be more useful for Unicode/DBCS characters, as you can see how they're stored internally and manipulate them.

Comment: Thank you Joe.  I realized the error in the case of the 'a'